# Generator vs Sequence object

Tags: python

I know the difference between `range` and `xrange`.
But I was surprised to see that `xrange` wasn't a`generator` but a `sequence object`.

What's the difference then, how to create a `sequence object` and when used it over a `generator`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason that `xrange` is a sequence object is because it supports the [sequence methods interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).  For example you can index it (which is something you can't do with a vanilla generator):

```
print xrange(30)[5]  # No Error
```

In other words,

- something is a sequence if it supports all of the methods defined in that link.
- If it's a generator, it probably only supports a [couple methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) (`.next` or `.__next__` are the most important)<sup>1</sup>.
- there's also an in-between land which is "iterable" -- "iterables" have a typically<sup>2</sup> defined `__iter__` method which returns "generator" (something with a well defined `.next` or `.__next__`<sup>3</sup> method)
- just to be complete, you'll often see people say "iterators" which are very similar to generators (implement `__iter__` which returns the object itself and has a well defined `next` and/or `__next__` method).

More formal definitions can be found in the [documentation glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

<sup><sup>1</sup>generators also support `__iter__` and simply return themselves. so techincally, all generators are also iterables (and iterators!), but not all iterables (iterators) are generators.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>`__len__` + `__getitem__` is enough to create an iterable as pointed out in the comments.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup>`__next__` is the method name for python3.x</sup>

Comment: Strings are iterables too and they don't have `__iter__` method on them, strings use `__getitem__`.

Comment: @200OK -- that's true in python2.x, but "fixed" in python3.x. `__getitem__` + `__len__` is also sufficient to create an iterable.

Comment: You should as well mention the word "iterator", which is an object returning itself from its `__iter__()` and having (`__`)`next`(`__`) as well. A generator is only one example of these. `iter([1, 2, 3])` has the same properties. Note that these are exhausted and unusable once used.

Comment: @glglgl -- Is that the real definition of "iterator"?  I always use it synchronously with "iterable"

Comment: @mgilson Yes. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) and especially [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Comment: "When an iterable object is passed as an argument to the built-in function `iter()`, it returns an iterator for the object." OTOH, "Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in most places where other iterables are accepted."

Comment: An important difference is: you can operate multiple times over an iterable (such as a list), but only once over an iterator (which is and remains exhausted afterwards). See `a = [1, 2, 3]; for i in a: print i; for i in a: print i; b = iter(a); for i in b: print i; for i in b: print i` (replace `;` by line breaks).

Comment: @glglgl -- Edited, Does that look correct enough? :-)

Comment: @mgilson Looks good. Except that, 'you'll often see people say "iterators"' - it's not only "people" who say this, it's the official docs. And maybe it might be worth noting that due to their implementing of `__iter__` they are iterables as well (unlike in Java, where a `java.lang.Iterable` is not (necessarily) a `java.util.Iterator` itself).

Answer (score 2):

A `sequence object` is a special, C-provided type.  A `generator` can be written by user code.

This is a Python 2 thing -- in Python 3:

```
>>> print(type(range(1)))
<class 'range'>
>>> print(type(xrange(1)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

Python2:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print type(xrange(1))
<type 'xrange'>
```

Comment: thanks but I already know the difference between python 2 and 3, but it's nice to see that the type is not the same between both version.

Comment: Downvoted. It's better to reason about the differences in terms of the interface provided, and not implementation details.